# Two dollars per hair means two dollars for every hair or two dollars for all the hair?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, grammatical-number

I was talking to my friend about cutting his hair when this came up. I wanted 2 dollars for every hair-strand that I cut but he said that since hair is plural, I would only get 2 dollars for the whole haircut.

Comment: Not plural, but uncountable (when referring to hair as a substance). _A hair_ (countable) is an individual strand.

Comment: Agree - per hair means per hair strand. per Head [of hair] would imply per haircut. Likewise, per thread would not equate to per shirt.

Comment: The question is not about the meaning of *hair*, by itself, nor about the meaning of *per*, by itself, but about the interaction of the two, and that arguably goes beyond what can be discovered by simply consulting a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

After "per" you need to have a count noun, so here you need to interpret "hair" in the countable sense, as referring to an individual strand of hair.

Comment: There may be an additional problem, both in this answer and in the question itself, due to the ambiguity of *strand* in the context of talking about hair: it can stand for a single hair or for something that is more than single hair but less than all the hair on a person's head (a lock of hair). Can *per hair* ever mean per strand of hair in the latter sense? Note that charging $2 per single hair would quickly make one a millionaire; charging $2 per strand in the latter sense would, although highly unusual, not be completely preposterous.